# Is there any JavaScript Grid plugin that have no framework dependency?

Tags: javascript

Is there any JavaScript Grid plugin that have no framework dependency?

Specifically, what I want is to be able to display a grid of information that could be sorted and searched as per column basis.

The best example that I have found of the kind of grid I'd like is SlickGrid.

This is an example of the sorting per column feature I want.

`http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html`

And this is an example of sorting the entries per column. You click on the column's header and entries are sorted.

`http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html`

But SlickGrid needs JQuery. I would rather not use JQuery, as I am interested in using a different JavaScript framework named Spark.

`http://sparkjs.co.uk/`

So I was looking for something I could use for a simple grid that just use those two features. Ajax sugar would be cool too, but not extremely important, for the moment.

Comment: good question, but I think grid is too complex thing to be lightweight in any way. but it depends on your unspecified requirements btw.

Comment: Grid is far too vague. What do you actually want? A HTML table enhancment plugin, There are hundreds of them, most of them are no good.

Comment: If you want a table enhancement plugin like @Raynos suggested, I don't think it's feasible to do it in pure JS anymore. JS libraries are just better suited to do this.

Comment: Trust me. You don't want a framework-less solution.

Comment: @Khez @ThiefMaster framework less solutions have their place. You can write a very small, specific & efficient table enhancement library yourself. It'll have to be hand written though. It's great for hand optimising for mobile platforms.

Comment: @Raynos the question was not regarding the possibility of doing it, but weather there is one done.

Comment: @Raynos: Good point. I added the exact features I am interested in.

Comment: @Nerian if you want to use Spark then write your own plugin for Spark. Otherwise just use jQuery. Sorting a table is 20 lines.

Comment: just found https://ag-grid.com ... going to give it a try. seems a little ugly, but the AG is for agnostic, so i'm in

Answer (score 2):

I needed to find a good JS grid component for a commercial web app. 2 years ago I checked several libraries and I chose Active Widgets' Grid component.

http://www.activewidgets.com/general.intro/

It does not have any external dependencies. Documentation could be better but the actual library creates really nice looking grids.

Comment: But that costs 500$ to use. There are cheaper alternatives.

Comment: @Raynos, yes it does. In the question it was not pointed out that the solution should be free. And there are always cheaper alternatives to anything. This component is good and I've been using it happily for a while now. If you are working in a commercial project and need a good grid component, this is your choise. No idea why this answer was unaccepted. This component has no Jquery or Prorotype dependencies.

Comment: If you are working on your pet project you may not want to pay $500 extra for a component. But, if you are working for a company or you have your own company, you really should calculate how much time / effort you are putting making your own grid or changing free component to suite your needs. Or you can buy one which has already features you really need.